# Adding JTable and JscrollPane to JPanel on button click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

Here what I am doing:

[image: Searching Panel]

On clicking Search flight, the data comes from Database and display on another `JFrame` like this:

[image: Result Panel]

**I want this data to be shown right below the searching panel instead of opening new frame.** Something like this:

[image: Desired Panel]

My codes are as follows:

listingFlight.java

```
public class listingFlight extends javax.swing.JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {
    public listingFlight() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //Netbeans autogenerated componnent code
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        this.jLabel3.setText(jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString()+" ("+jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column+1).toString()+")");
        this.jLabel4.setText(jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column+2).toString()+" ("+jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column+3).toString()+")");
        this.jLabel6.setText(jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column+9).toString());

        this.jLabel8.setText(jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column+6).toString());
        this.jLabel11.setText(jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column+8).toString());
        this.jLabel12.setText(jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column+7).toString());
        this.jLabel15.setText(jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column+4).toString());
        this.jLabel16.setText(jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column+5).toString());

        return this;

    }

}
```

(on clicking button "Search Flight", i m performing this.)

```
try {
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("select s.airportName,s.cityName,d.airportName,d.cityName,f.srcTime,f.destTime,f.flightNumber,f.availability,f.price,a.airlineName,f.flightID from flights f inner join airlines a on(a.airlineID=f.flightName) inner join cityinfo s on(s.cityID=f.src) inner join cityinfo d on(d.cityID=f.dest) where f.src=" + jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex() + " and f.dest=" + jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex());
                while (rs.next()) {
                    i++;
                }
                rs.beforeFirst();
                data = new Object[i][11];
                i = 0;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    data[i][0] = rs.getString(1);
                    data[i][1] = rs.getString(2);
                    data[i][2] = rs.getString(3);
                    data[i][3] = rs.getString(4);
                    data[i][4] = rs.getString(5);
                    data[i][5] = rs.getString(6);
                    data[i][6] = rs.getString(7);
                    data[i][7] = rs.getString(8);
                    data[i][8] = rs.getString(9);
                    data[i][9] = rs.getString(10);
                    data[i][10] = rs.getString(11);
                    i++;
                }

                table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("override")
                    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
                        return new listingFlight();
                    }
                };
                showFrame(table);
                table.setRowHeight(82);
                conn.close();
            }
```

For now `showFrame()` is :

```
  private void showFrame(JTable table) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Search Result");
        f.setSize(800, 700);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
```

But i m trying to add `jScrollPane` to existing `JPanel` instead of creating new `JFrame` and displaying Data to it

```
  private void showFrame(JTable table) {


        this.jPanel1.add(new JScrollPane(table));

    }
```

This showFrame is not adding JScrollPane to my existing jPanel1.

Comment: Call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on `jPanel1` after adding the scrollpane. (Also make sure the panel has the right layout)

Comment: @LuxxMiner u mean something like this: `this.jPanel1.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        this.jPanel1.revalidate();
        this.jPanel1.repaint();`
it didn't worked

Comment: By the way, your `TableCellRenderer` is wrong, it should be focused on rendering only a single cell value

Comment: Generally speaking, your `JTable` should already be added to the container, then all you do is update the `TableModel`.  At a guess, I'm guessing you're using a `null` layout (or have used a form editor of some kind to design the initial layout)

Comment: @MadProgrammer should I use `TableCellEditor`?

Comment: @MishraShreyanshu Nope, same problem.  A renderer/editor should be responsible for a single column of data, not all of it.  Either use the `JTable` the way it was designed to be used or use something else